# Java: How do I catch an exception created inside the Method.invoke?

Tags: java, exception, invoke

It seems like I can't catch exceptions in my code when the method was called from the Method.invoke method. How can catch it from inside the method itself?

```
void function() {
  try {
    // code that throws exception
  }
  catch( Exception e ) {
    // it never gets here!! It goes straight to the try catch near the invoke
  }
}

try {
  return method.invoke(callTarget, args);
}
catch( InvocationTargetException e ) {
  // exception thrown in code that throws exception get here!
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking exceptions end with the name Exception and errors end with the name Error. Errors and Exceptions are not the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason that you can't catch `UnsatisfiedLinkError` with `Exception` is that `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is not a subclasses of `Exception`.  In fact, it is a subclass of `Error`.

You should be careful about catching Error exceptions.  They almost always indicate that something really bad has happened, and in most cases it is not possible to recover from them safely.  For instance, an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` means that the JVM can't find a native library ... and that whatever depended on that library is (probably) unusable.  Generally speaking. `Error` exceptions should be treated as fatal errors.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the real cause of the `MethodInvocationException` by checking its `getCause()` method that will return the exception thrown from `function()`

*Note*: you might need to call `getCause()` recursively on the returned exceptions to arrive at yours.

*Note*: `getCause()` returns a `Throwable`, which you will have to check for its actual type (e.g. `instanceof` or `getClass()`)

*Note*: `getCause()` returns `null` if no more "cause" is available -- you have arrived at the base cause of the execption thrown

**Update**:

The reason why the `catch()` in `function()` is not getting executed is that `xxxError` is not an `Exception`, so your `catch` won't catch it -- declare either `catch(Throwable)` or `catch(Error)` in `function()` if you don't want to declare all specific errors -- note that this is usually a bad idea (what are you going to dio with an `OutOfMemoryError`?.

Comment: what you said helped me understand the issue. It seems like we cant use Exception to catch exceptions. From my understanding, you need to specify the exact exception type to be able to catch it when calling from invoke.

For instance:
catch( UnsatisfiedLinkError e ) instead of catch( Exception e ).
'

Comment: @user1459231 - I just read the fine print. The problem is that `xxxError` is not an `Exception`, so your `catch` won't catch it -- declare either `catch(Throwable)` or `catch(Error)` in `function()`.

Comment: Errors and Exceptions both extend Throwable, but errors are not a subclass of Exception and do not get caught by it.  You can catch Throwable to get both, but(I cannot stress this enough) this is very poor form and can cause problems later.  Especially since it will also catch things like StackOverflowError, which you really aren't equipped to handle in your code.

Comment: catch(Exception e) doesn't catch UnsatisfiedLinkError inside an invoke or not.

Answer (score 0):

You throw exceptions as normal. The fact its inside an invoke makes no difference.

```
public class B {
    public static void function() {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Caught normally");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException {
        Method method = B.class.getMethod("function");
        Object callTarget = null;
        try {
            method.invoke(callTarget, args);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // should never get called.
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
Caught normally
java.lang.Exception
at B.function(B.java:15)
... deleted ...
at B.main(B.java:26)
... deleted ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`MethodInvocationException` means you're calling the method wrong, it shouldn't have even gotten to inside your try block.  From the docs:

```
Signals that the method with the specified signature could not be invoked with the provided arguments.
```

Edit: That's if this is the Spring MethodInvokationException, the Apache Velocity one does wrap function exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Following Attila's hint I ended up doing this:

```
void function() {
  try {
    method.invoke(callTarget, args);
    
  }
  catch( Throwable e ) {
    Throwable throwEx = e.getCause();
    assertEquals("expectedErrorMessage", e.getCause().getMessage()); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).